# Can we configure or install SquirrelMail or any other aplication in localhost(xammp or wamp)?

Tags: php, xampp, wamp, squirrelmail

I have a question which looks strange for me.
can we configure or install any application like SquirrelMail inside our localhost(xampp or wamp) to access our emails, I need something like ms-outlook and thunderbird which can be installed and configured in windows, but I don't configure it in windows I want to configure and install it in my xampp or wamp server.

is there any solution ? please help me!
Thank you

Comment: Not that strange! Its basically the same as your last question!

Comment: Yes it is duplicate, I guess my last question was not so clear , I tried to give more details of question.